# How to set test duration in cppUnit xml report for Jenkins?

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, xunit, cppunit

I'm using cppUnit for testing framework and Jenkins for continuous integration. I've set xUnit Plugin for Jenkins to parse xml test reports and it works fine.

There's only one problem: cppUnit xml outputter does not add test duration to report. I can do it by CppUnit::XmlOutputterHook, but I dont know what to add.

When I try to do something like

```
<Test id="1">
  <Name>test_0001</Name>
  <Time>0.01</Time>
</Test>
```

then Jenkins reports an error:

```
[xUnit] [ERROR] - The result file '<file name here>' for the metric 'CppUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped.
```

So, my question is: how to report a valid cppUnit xml for xUnit Jenkins plugin with test duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using "custom tool" report type with with [custom stylesheet](https://github.com/vok1980/xunit-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/xunit/types/customTool/testcase1/input.xsl) instead of "CppUnit-1.12.1" in xUnit plugin